# 500 System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException when making an Ajax call to WCF rest service

Tags: ajax, wcf

Ajax Call:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://SomeService/ServiceName.svc/GetSearchResults",
        data: JSON.stringify({ parameters: serviceParameters }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "XML",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#xmlText").text(response.xml);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.toString);
        }
    })
```

WCF Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                    UriTemplate = "GetSearchResults")]
        XElement GetSearchResults(inputParameters parameters);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "getFile")]
        Stream GetFile(DocInfo info);
```

Web.config:

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>

 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

 <system.serviceModel>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
   </serviceHostingEnvironment>
   <standardEndpoints>
     <webHttpEndpoint>
       <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"></standardEndpoint>
     </webHttpEndpoint>
   </standardEndpoints>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

The service is hosted on IIS6.

When I call the service I get the following error message:

```
500 System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException
```

I can call the `GetFile` method and get the response stream but I get the error message when calling `GetSearchResults`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you to enable tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and inspect the trace log for the exact problem when trying to invoke the GetSearchResults method

Answer (score 17):

I encountered this error for the reason mentioned below

Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (258187264 bytes) is less than 5% of total memory.  As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests.  To resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element.

Comment: I was able to confirm this was my problem by searching for errors in my Windows Event Log (Application). Updating the web.config to set minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" did fix the issue.

Comment: However you do need full trust (Administrator Privileges) on your machine to get minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService work..

Answer (score 9):

Many thanks for your inspired replies and comments.

I actually encountered the same error but with different story:

At first, I got "404 (Not Found)" server error, which is because I did not have a transport for "HTTPS" as well as I already have one for the "HTTP".

I added a `<httpsTransport>` to my `<binding>` element, so it looked like this:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding_ITheService">
      <httpTransport keepAliveEnabled="True" transferMode="Streamed" authenticationScheme="None" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" manualAddressing="true" />
      <httpsTransport keepAliveEnabled="True" transferMode="Streamed" authenticationScheme="None" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" manualAddressing="true" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Then I got the `500 System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException` error. However, I navigated "Event Viewer > Windows Log > Application" and found that "transports cannot be defined more than a time for the same binding". So, I decided to add an additional endpoint with a new binding for the "HTTPS" transport.

At the end, my configuration looks like the following:

```
<services>
  <service name="TheService" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpBehavior_ITheService">
    <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_ITheService" contract="ITheService" behaviorConfiguration="EndPointBehavior_ITheService" />
    <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_ITheService_Secured" contract="ITheService" behaviorConfiguration="EndPointBehavior_ITheService" />
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding_ITheService">
      <httpTransport keepAliveEnabled="True" transferMode="Streamed" authenticationScheme="None" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" manualAddressing="true" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding_ITheService_Secured">
      <httpsTransport keepAliveEnabled="True" transferMode="Streamed" authenticationScheme="None" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" manualAddressing="true" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Then every things goes the right way and works perfectly.

**In case you develop on visual Studio and use IIS-Express "*Cassini*", remember to enable SSL option in the properties of the website-project, that tells IIS-Express to prepare a base URL for the HTTPS transport that you previously added to binding.**

Comment: The hint to look in the event viewer was of great value to me

Answer (score 1):

[Add site binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tubbh.png)Go to the IIS => then Default Website=> right Click on that => Edit Bindings=> click on ADD Button=> add HTTPS bindings there

Details ARE in shown screenshot

Comment: click on ADD site binding to shown image and this work for me